# getElementById and addEventListener is not working on my HTML

Tags: javascript, html, css

It's supposed to be a pop-up box on the bottom-right section of the page. There a minimize button on the pop-up. Once clicked, the pop-up would be hidden and the maximize button would turn visible.
I need to change the style property, which is visibility in JavaScript. Turning "visible" to "hidden" and vice versa.

```js
let calculateMinimize = document.getElementById("calculate-minimize");
let calculateMaximize = document.getElementById("calculate-maximize");
let calculateContainer = document.getElementById("calculate-container");

calculateMinimize.addEventListener("click", function () {
  calculateContainer.style.visibility = "hidden";
});
```

```css
#calculate-container {
  position: fixed;
  background-color: #a8baa9;
  width: 30%;
  height: 30vh;
  min-width: 300px;
  min-height: 200px;
  bottom: 10px;
  right: 10px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  box-shadow: 10px 10px 5px rgb(50, 50, 50, 0.7);
  visibility: visible;
}

#calculate-minimize {
  background-color: #fff5cf;
  width: 100%;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 10px 10px 0px 0px;
  height: 30px;
  color: #a8baa9;
  font-size: 20px;
}
#calculate-maximize {
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 0px;
  right: 10px;
  width: 30%;
  height: 30px;
  min-width: 300px;
  border-radius: 10px 10px 0px 0px;
  border-bottom: none;
  box-shadow: 5px -5px 5px rgb(50, 50, 50, 0.7);
  background-color: #beaf87;
  border: none;
  font-size: 20px;
  color: #fff;
  visibility: hidden;
}
```

```html
<body>
   <div id="calculate-container">
      <button id="calculate-minimize">^</button>
   </div>
   <button id="calculate-maximize">^</button>
</body>
```

Comment: Please explain in more details what it is you want, what you've already done, and where you are stuck. It's not clear what the result should be.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

using `toggle` a class `hide` with JS(No need to use `visibility`).

```js
let calculateMinimize = document.getElementById("calculate-minimize");
let calculateMaximize = document.getElementById("calculate-maximize");
let calculateContainer = document.getElementById("calculate-container");

const buttons = [calculateMinimize, calculateMaximize];
buttons.forEach((btn) =>
  btn.addEventListener("click", function() {
    calculateContainer.classList.toggle("hide");
    calculateMaximize.classList.toggle("hide");
  })
);

// or
/*
[calculateMinimize, calculateMaximize].forEach((btn) =>
    btn.addEventListener("click", () => {
        [calculateContainer, calculateMaximize].forEach((c) =>
            c.classList.toggle("hide")
        );
    })
);
*/
```

```css
#calculate-container {
  position: fixed;
  background-color: #a8baa9;
  width: 30%;
  height: 30vh;
  min-width: 300px;
  min-height: 200px;
  bottom: 10px;
  right: 10px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  box-shadow: 10px 10px 5px rgb(50, 50, 50, 0.7);
}

#calculate-minimize {
  background-color: #fff5cf;
  width: 100%;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 10px 10px 0px 0px;
  height: 30px;
  color: #a8baa9;
  font-size: 20px;
}

#calculate-maximize {
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 0px;
  right: 10px;
  width: 30%;
  height: 30px;
  min-width: 300px;
  border-radius: 10px 10px 0px 0px;
  border-bottom: none;
  box-shadow: 5px -5px 5px rgb(50, 50, 50, 0.7);
  background-color: #beaf87;
  border: none;
  font-size: 20px;
  color: #fff;
}

.hide {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div id="calculate-container">
    <button id="calculate-minimize">^</button>
  </div>
  <button id="calculate-maximize" class="hide">^</button>
</body>
```

Answer (score 1):

I cannot see the problem with getElementById and addEventListener, but you should handle both elements each time the user interacts with the buttons.

```js
let calculateMinimize = document.getElementById("calculate-minimize");
let calculateMaximize = document.getElementById("calculate-maximize");
let calculateContainer = document.getElementById("calculate-container");

calculateMinimize.addEventListener("click", function() {
  calculateContainer.style.visibility = "hidden";
  calculateMaximize.style.visibility = "visible";
});

calculateMaximize.addEventListener("click", function() {
  calculateContainer.style.visibility = "visible";
  calculateMaximize.style.visibility = "hidden";
});
```

```css
#calculate-container {
  position: fixed;
  background-color: #a8baa9;
  width: 30%;
  height: 30vh;
  min-width: 300px;
  min-height: 200px;
  bottom: 10px;
  right: 10px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  box-shadow: 10px 10px 5px rgb(50, 50, 50, 0.7);
  visibility: visible;
}

#calculate-minimize {
  background-color: #fff5cf;
  width: 100%;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 10px 10px 0px 0px;
  height: 30px;
  color: #a8baa9;
  font-size: 20px;
}

#calculate-maximize {
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 0px;
  right: 10px;
  width: 30%;
  height: 30px;
  min-width: 300px;
  border-radius: 10px 10px 0px 0px;
  border-bottom: none;
  box-shadow: 5px -5px 5px rgb(50, 50, 50, 0.7);
  background-color: #beaf87;
  border: none;
  font-size: 20px;
  color: #fff;
  visibility: hidden;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div id="calculate-container">
    <button id="calculate-minimize">^</button>
  </div>
  <button id="calculate-maximize">^</button>
</body>
```

Alternative:

```js
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', e => {
  let calculateContainer = document.getElementById("calculate-container");
  let calculateContainercontent = calculateContainer.querySelector('div');

  calculateContainer.querySelector('a').addEventListener('click', e => {
    e.preventDefault();
    calculateContainercontent.classList.toggle('hidden');
  });
});
```

```css
#calculate-container {
  position: fixed;
  background-color: #a8baa9;
  width: 30%;
  bottom: 10px;
  right: 10px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  box-shadow: 10px 10px 5px rgb(50, 50, 50, 0.7);
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

#calculate-container>a {
  display: block;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-align: center;
  padding-top: 5px;
  background-color: #fff5cf;
  width: 100%;
  border-radius: 10px 10px 0px 0px;
  color: #a8baa9;
  font-size: 20px;
}

#calculate-container>div {
  min-height: 100px;
}

div.hidden {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div id="calculate-container">
    <a href="control">^</a>
    <div>content</div>
  </div>
</body>
```